# Implement Phalcon 4 Database Existence validator (similar to Uniqueness)

Tags: phalcon

Often I need to validate if given value is existing in certain column (attribute) of a table (model).

This can be useful in foreign keys of a model, to check if the given values exists.

Most probably the validation logic can be mostly the same as for Uniqueness, except the comparison here can be something like > 0.

A possible usage scenario could be like below:

```
$validator->add(
    'organization_id',
    new ExistenceOnDbValidator(
        [
            'model' => Organization::class,
            'expr'=> ' id = %s ',
            'excludeNullValue'=> true,
            'message' => 'Organization does not exist.',
        ]
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I implemented myself a validator called ExistenceOnDbValidator and it works fine.

Usage

```
$validator = new Validation();

$validator->add(
    'organization_id',
    new ExistenceOnDbValidator(
        [
            'model' => Organization::class,
            'expr' => ' id = %s ',
            'ignoreNullValue' => false,
            'message' => 'Selected organization does not exist.',
        ]
    )
);
```

Implenentation

```
use Phalcon\Messages\Message;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\AbstractValidator;
use Phalcon\Validation\ValidatorInterface;

class ExistenceOnDb extends AbstractValidator implements ValidatorInterface
{

    public function validate(Validation $validator, $attribute): bool
    {
        $expr = $this->getOption('expr');
        $model = $this->getOption('model');
        $value = $validator->getValue($attribute);
        $ignoreNullValue = true;

        if ($this->hasOption('ignoreNullValue')) {
            $ignoreNullValue = $this->getOption('ignoreNullValue');
        }

        if ((is_null($value) || empty($value)) && $ignoreNullValue == true) {
            return true;
        }

        $expr = sprintf(
            $expr,
            $value,
        );

        $result = $model::findFirst($expr);

        if ((is_null($result) || empty($result))) {

            $message = $this->getOption('message');

            $validator->appendMessage(new Message($message));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```